# Can a plpython function take multiple rows as parameter?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, plpython

I need to know that to make functions that take multiple rows of arrays and returns a result array.

For example:

Table some_table

```
id | num_array
1  | [1,1,1]
2  | [2,2,2]
```

Then running:

```
SELECT custom_avg(num_array) FROM some_table;
```

And get a an array with the element-wise operation (avg in this example):

```
[1.5, 1.5, 1.5]
```

Something like the standard aggregate functions that operate over rows.

After almost 2 hours of looking at docs and googling I can't find a straight answer to this.

I know the array can be unrolled into a table but I'm trying to avoid that. 
If this kind of functions can be solved with standard SQL that would be useful too.

Comment: Your example is not very clear. You want the avg for each array element, right? Please clarify. And, as always, add your version of Postgres.

Comment: Yes, your interpretation was right, I'll edit the question for further reference. Version of postgres is unimportant, I can use whichever solves the problem best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Function

Postgres functions cannot take tables ("multiple rows") as parameter. [Per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html):

> The argument types can be base, composite, or domain types, or can
> reference the type of a table column.

You would pass a table by reference using a cursor or a temp table ...

#### SQL

But you can solve most anything with plain SQL.
To compute an average for every position in a one-dimensional array column:

You did not provide your version, so I am assuming the current one. `WITH ORDINALITY` requires Postgres **9.4**:

```
SELECT ARRAY (
   SELECT avg(elem) AS avg_elem
   FROM   tbl t
        , unnest (t.num_array) WITH ORDINALITY a(elem, rn)
   GROUP  BY a.rn
   ORDER  BY a.rn
   ) AS arr_avg;
```

Basically:

1. unnest each array in a `LATERAL` join (implicit here), remembering the ordinal position of elements
2. `GROUP BY` this position.
3. Construct a resulting array, ordered by this position.

There are less elegant alternatives in older versions. For Postgres **9.3**:

```
SELECT ARRAY (
   SELECT avg(t.num_array[i]) AS avg_elem
   FROM   tbl t, generate_subscripts(t.num_array, 1) i
   GROUP  BY i
   ORDER  BY i
   ) AS arr_avg;
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/b3c78/4)

More:

- [PostgreSQL unnest() with element number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8760419/postgresql-unnest-with-element-number/8767450#8767450)

Comment: Very good answer, thx. 
**WITH ORDINALITY** is the key component I was missing. Seems that searching in google without the exact keywords has become useless nowadays :P